# API responding with 500 through browser, but works with Postman

Tags: php, apache, slim

I'm building a site that uses Angular as my frontend, PHP Slim as my API, and Apache. I have a particular post call which when run though Postman, works, so I implemented it on the site, but it returns a 500 there, with the following as the error in the console:

```
POST (myurl) 500 (Internal Server Error)
Failed to load (myurl): No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '(my domain)' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response (myurl) with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening, or how to debug it. I thought maybe it was an issue with POST calls, but my login POST call works fine. I can't figure out if it's exclusively Apache, or if it's from PHP. I have code that does the preflight check:

```
return $response
    ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', env('FRONTEND_DOMAIN'))
    ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', implode(',', $methods))
    ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
```

So the headers should be fine (other calls are working).

Comment: show the request that you make, Make sure you access-controll allow origin in the header

Answer (score 1):

You have to check that in postman you do not have "SSL certificate verification" disabled and if it is deactivated, API calls must follow this criterion.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MqZI.png)